# How to use Django Orm Subqueries in this sql

Tags: django, django-orm

I'm new to `Django ORM` and I found it difficult to use Django Subqueries in this `sql` statement since I didn't found a nested `select .. from (select...` example in `django orm` :

these are my models:

```
class A:
     published_at = models.DateTimeField(_('Published at'))
     ....

Class B:

     pub=models.ForeignKey('A', verbose_name=_('A'), blank=True, null=True,
                          on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
     prices= models.FloatField(_('Price'), blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)
     soc = models.IntegerField(_('SOC'), blank=True, null=True,
                               db_index=True)
```

and this is `SQL`

```
select DATE_FORMAT(`A`.`published_at`, '%Y-%m-%d'), sum(b)
    from (
   select `B`.`pub_id` as c, soc, avg(prices) as b
   from B
   group by c, soc
    ) as ch
   INNER JOIN `A` ON (c = `A`.`id`)
   group by DATE_FORMAT(`A`.`published_at`, '%Y-%m-%d');
```

is using `subqueries in this situation usuful? I'm using django 1.11

please help

**Update**

When I tried the solution suggested by `Endre Both` I got this error

```
           Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.6/site- 
       packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3296, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
        File "<ipython-input-7-824230af12bd>", line 5, in <module>
.annotate(total=Sum('avg'))
      File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 948, in annotate
clone.query.add_annotation(annotation, alias, is_summary=False)
      File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 973, in add_annotation
summarize=is_summary)
       File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/aggregates.py", line 19, in resolve_expression
c = super(Aggregate, self).resolve_expression(query, allow_joins, reuse, summarize)
     File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/expressions.py", line 548, in resolve_expression
c.source_expressions[pos] = arg.resolve_expression(query, allow_joins, reuse, summarize, for_save)
      File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/expressions.py", line 471, in resolve_expression
return query.resolve_ref(self.name, allow_joins, reuse, summarize)
        File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1472, in resolve_ref
return self.annotation_select[name]
    KeyError: 'avg'
```

Comment: If the SQL syntax were valid (I don't think it is, have you run it?), you seem to be joining on two primary keys. I don't see how this can make sense.

Comment: If there is a relationship between two models, use [Django relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/) to express that.

Comment: yes there is a relashionship that  I forgot to mention..could you please see my edit

Answer (score 0):

If you first want to calculate average prices over `pub_id` and `soc` and then sum up those averages for pubs that have the same published date, you may be looking for this:

```
from django.db.models import FloatField, OuterRef, Subquery, Sum, Avg

sq = Subquery(B.objects
               .filter(pub_id=OuterRef('id'), soc=OuterRef('b__soc'))
               .values('pub_id', 'soc')
               .annotate(avg=Avg('prices'))
               .values('avg'),
              output_field=FloatField()
             )

results = (A.objects
            .values('id', 'published_at', 'b__soc')
            .annotate(avg=sq)
            .values('published_at')
            .annotate(total=Sum('avg'))
           )
```

Having written this up blind, I'm curious if I've got it right. This might be one of those cases where a raw SQL query is easier to understand.

BTW, what's the usefulness of summing up averages without any weighting?

Comment: Thanks for your nice response.. Actually when I run the code of `results` it gave me an error `NameError: name 'avg' is not defined` in `annotate`

Comment: I don't see why this would happen. Try renaming `avg` in the second (results) query to something else (both occurrences) to see if the problem is in the subquery or the main query.

Comment: I tried that but the same error occurs. I tried even to remove quotes .

Comment: What Django version do you use? It works in 2.1 for me. You'd have to include the full stack trace in your question to tell more.

Comment: I'm using django 1.11.. ok just a minute I will do

Comment: You could test replacing `.values('published_at')` with `.values('published_at', 'avg')`. This removes the error but it will probably prevent the values from being summed up as `avg` will be included in the `group_by` (at least that's how it works in 2.1). If the query runs; you can print `str(results.query)` and post it.